# Is it possible to segment video on equal size(in terms of Data) chunks?

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-processing

I am trying to implement a buffer based algorithm for my research. I was wondering is there any software/tool that can segment video based on equal data size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would most likely have to write it yourself. Media buffers based on size are not very useful in the real world because they drain at a variable rate whereas time moves at a constant rate. Thus media buffers tend to target a duration instead of a size. Hence tools are not likely to focus on such a feature. You could encode a file with a constant bitrate using something like intra frame refresh, and get pretty consistent results.